# Why does everyone keep using torsion balances for measuring the gravitational constant?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, experimental-physics, measurements, physical-constants, si-units

Most of the experiments aimed at measuring the gravitational constant use very complex setups involving suspended balls (Cavendish-like experiments).

This is however not exactly the ideal setup – and in fact Big G is one of the least known constants. The biggest problems with the Cavendish setup are:

- The forces are *really* tiny
- Every object in the room influences the experiment (including the scientists walking in the room, whose mass is often larger than the test masses used)
- A sphere is not the ideal shape for measuring a force that decreases with the square of the distance; a plate is.

Why does no one use the following setup?

A $1\,\mathrm{m} \times 1\,\mathrm{m} \times 0.1\,\mathrm{m}$ lead plate is at rest on a balance.

[image]

After its weight is accurately measured, another similar plate is slided right *under* it.

[image]

If the distance between the two plates is within $1\,\mathrm{cm}$, the first plate should become 0.35 grams heavier, which is well within the range of high precision balances.

Or, even better, using liquid mercury instead of a sliding plate should solve all the practical issues related to moving heavy weights.

**EDIT**

Apparently someone [has attempted](https://www.europhysicsnews.org/articles/epn/pdf/2000/04/epn00406.pdf) to perform a similar measurement using 7 tonnes of mercury (see [this article](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0375-9601(98)00699-9) for more details).

Comment: "the first plate should become 2-3 grams heavier" That sounds off by many, many orders of magnitude -- how did you get that number?

Comment: @knzhou There was a small mistake in the radius, but not “orders of magnitude” (corrected). That number is the result of $F=G\frac{m_1m_2}{r^2}$ divided by $9.807$ ($1\,\mathrm{N}  = \frac{1}{9.807}\,\mathrm{kg}$), where $r$ (the distance between the two plates' centers of mass) is $11\,\mathrm{cm}$ and $m$ is $1129\,\mathrm{kg}$ for both plates. Therefore, $6.67408 \times 10^{-11} \times \frac{ 1129^2 }{ 0.11^2 \times 9.807 }= 0.0007169\,\mathrm{kg}$.

Comment: Your calculation - I’m sorry to say - is completely wrong: you cannot concentrate the masses as point masses and divide by the distance.  You need to integrate over the mass distributions, and account for the relative distance between each pairs of volume elements.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero I assumed that knowing the centre of mass was enough. Before you go further, assuming that the same two masses were spheres made of lead ($r = 288 \times 2 + 10 = 676\,\mathrm{mm}$), the upper sphere would weigh 1 milligram more after the second ball is rolled under it. The order of magnitude we are dealing with is above the milligram.

Comment: Here's another issue. our balance needs to resolve better than 0.0001 kg (100 mg) yet handle a load of 1 tonne. Please find me such a balance.

Comment: @hdhondt You balance the plate when is at rest using a conterweight. Then any minimum change in weight can be measured by a high-precision balance.

Comment: How much do you think such sphere would weigh? see https://ultraray.com/calculator/result/

Comment: @ZeroTheHero I used $1129\,\mathrm{kg}$ for my calculations.

Comment: it’s actually about 10x that… i.e. more than 10000kg…. need to measure milligrams (if that’s even an accurate order of magnitude) out of $10^5$kg…like 1 part in $10^{11}$ or something like this…

Comment: @ZeroTheHero If you are talking about the spheres, the distance ($r$) is twice the radius plus one centimetre. The radius of each sphere ($r_s$) is $288\,\mathrm{mm}$. Knowing that the density of lead is $11290\,\mathrm{kg/m^3}$, one obtains $m = \frac{4}{3} \pi r_s^3 \rho = \frac{4}{3} \pi \times 0.288^3 \times 11290 = 1129.6\,\mathrm{kg}$.

Comment: well whatever: it would make this 1 part in $10^{10}$ instead…

Answer (score 1):

The Cavendish type of experiment used the time period $T$ of the oscillation to determine $G$.  Disturbances from outside could be made insignificant.

[image]

(from [here](https://www.school-for-champions.com/science/gravitation_cavendish_experiment.htm#.Yc7dvsvP3IU))

$$G=\frac{2\pi^2 Lr^2\theta}{MT^2}$$

where $\theta$ is the angle that the bar turns.

The experiment achieved an accuracy of $0.6$ percent.

The method in your question does give a change in force $\Delta F$ of about $8.5\times 10^{-3}$ Newtons assuming two weights $10$ cm apart of the same mass of the lead plates.  As the mass is spread out let's estimate  $\Delta F = 5\times 10^{-3}$ N.

$G$ would be determined from $$G=\frac{FR^2}{M^2}$$ where we could assume that the distance between the plates $R$ and the mass of each plate $M$ were known to within
$0.6$ percent.

However to improve on the Cavendish experiment, you would have to measure the change in weight of the top lead plate to $0.6$ percent of $\Delta F = 5\times 10^{-3}$, that's $3\times 10^{-5}$ Newtons.

The lead plate weights about $11,000$ Newtons, so your looking for a change of about $1$ part in $370$ million.

As mentioned in the comments, there are balances that can weigh very light weights, but not a heavy weight and also detect such a small change.

It might be possible to set up a system of rotating masses e.g. 4, that pass under the top plate and try and generate a resonance and look for that - but then you'd be back to a Cavendish type experiment on a bigger scale.

If the scale of the Cavendish experiment improved the accuracy, there would have been such experiments by now, so it seems that increasing the scale doesn't improve the accuracy.

According to [this website](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_constant) in 2018 there was an attempt to improve the accuracy using 'atom interferometry' but groups were also still using the torsion balance method and it's still regarded as the best method.

Comment: _“As mentioned in the comments, there are balances that can weigh very light weights, but not a heavy weight and also detect such a small change.”_ How about using a counterweight to balance the plate _exactly_ (possibly using magnetic bearings), and then using a high precision balance for measuring the micrograms as soon as the other plate is slided right under it?

Comment: @moonblink It would be great if someone could get it to work.  The torque produced by friction at the pivot would have to be made very small, that's probably the main difficulty.  You could try sending a design to a journal that specialises in experimental physics for more feedback.  Best of luck with it.

Comment: Thank you, John. The torque at the pivot point can be erased completely using magnetic levitation (frictionless balance). My plate weighs just a tonne, and considering also the counterweight we are talking about two tonnes. Magnetic bearings can support loads weighing up to several tonnes.

Comment: @moonblink  Ok, you should also check that there can be no sideways movement, as that would interfere with the measurement.

Comment: I imagined the plate suspended by a long cable. The precision balance can be placed half a way along the cable and use the cable for its measurements.

Comment: @moonblink, it's a good idea that you could pursue if you want, there are likely to be lots of technical issues, such as how much of the extra force is supported by the cable and how much by the magnetic bearings, changes due to temperature fluctuations etc...I thought of something similar where the second lead plate passed above, and the balancing one floated in mercury, then using an optical interference method to see if the balancing mass fell slightly, but these things in reality would not be easy to make accurate, all the best with it

Comment: @JohnHunter This is a problem that goes back hundreds of years.  Not to be discouraging to the OP, but if this were feasible someone else would have done it already.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero, yes, getting an accurate measurement of $G$ has been a problem for a while now, although it's good people are still having a go

Comment: @JohnHunter If the counterweight floating in mercury was possible it would be the ideal setup. The problem is that mercury will create its own gravitation and mess up the entire experiment – I mean, the counterweight _will_ move, but not strictly according to Archimedes' principle, as the more the counterweight goes up the less it will be attracted to the mercury. It's a small effect, but it is there. This is the reason why I had placed my tiny precision balance somewhere high on the cable, so that any gravitational interference becomes negligible. The purest setup is when nothing moves.

Comment: @moonblink, yes the float could be on an extended hollow tube.  That's the trouble, the more extra effects are accounted for the more complicated the setup gets, leading to other factors that could effect the experiment.  The good thing about the Cavendish experiment is that it's simple and the motion is horizontal, so nothing moved vertically.  Will have to leave it now, but if you ever have a go it would be interesting to hear about it...

Comment: @JohnHunter I really don't know if this is the best possible setup. But I do know that _the best possible setup is static_ (no moving objects, only compensating forces). If all you do is sliding a plate and then “push back” the force that appears using a precision balance, trying to keep the system exactly in the same position, the room can have all the irregularities that you want, but the new force will still be 100% coming from one single object: the slided plate. There will be only exactly _one_ interference: the slided plate will slightly attract the cables above the suspended plate too.